# fitz.open() not working when in a for loop (FITZ,PYTHON,PYMUPDF)

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I am getting stuck when trying to iterate through files in a directory ('PDFS') with fitz from PyMuPDF.
The thing is, the code works when I am just doing document = "somepdf.pdf", but as soon as I insert a for loop and try to access files that way this error shows up:

*filename, stream, filetype, rect, width, height, fontsize
RuntimeError: cannot open sample.pdf: No such file or directory*

Here is the code:

```
for file in os.listdir('PDFS'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.pdf'):
            document = file
            doc = fitz.open(document)
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your pdf files to open is under sub-directory `PDFS`, e.g. `PDFS/sample.pdf`, while your code `fitz.open(document)` is to open file under current working directory. So, a fix should be:

```py
import fitz
import os
import fnmatch

for file in os.listdir('PDFS'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.pdf'):
        document = os.path.join('PDFS', file)
        doc = fitz.open(document)
```

Furthermore, a relative path `PDFS` is used, so you have to run the code right under the path where `PDFS` in, say `/your/workspace/`:

```
/your/workspace > python code.py
```

Otherwise,

```
/your > python workspace/code.py

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'PDFS'
```

So, a good practice is to

- use full path if `PDFS` is just a user input path; otherwise,
- use relative path to the script path

  ```
  script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
  project_path = os.path.dirname(script_path)
  pdfs_path = os.path.join(project_path, 'PDFS')
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Its because PyCharm automatically installs the module named fitz whereas you need to write the following in the terminal:

```
pip install PyMuPDF
```

This will automatically install fitz and you can use the function ***fitz.open()***

Comment: Is it really true that PyCharm can automatically install a package based on an `import` statement? It does not do this for me (PyCharm-2023.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

There are two packages with the same name 'fitz'. I just had this same issue inside PyCharm 2022.2.3. My solution was:

1. Uninstall fitz 0.0.1.dev2
2. Install PymuPDF 1.23.3 (also known as 'fitz') from: https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/
3. Access via 'import fitz'.

I did notice along the way if fitz 0.0.1dev2 is installed alongside fitz 1.23.3 (AKA PymuPDF) can be accessed via "import fitz_new".